# Error message installing App from AppExchange

Tags: sandbox, appexchange, hierarchy

I am tryin to install the App "Any Record Hierarchy" (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G12hNUAR) from AppExchange on my Sandbox, but i get an error:
Problem:

1. Unexpected Error
   The package installation failed. Please provide the following information to the publisher:

Organization Name: ....
Organization ID: ....
Package: AnyRecordHierarchyv2
Version: 3.0
Error Message: The post install script failed.

What could go wrong? I installed this app yesterday on my dev org and it was working fine.

Comment: I would suggest to check with the developer of the app. That would be the quickest possible way.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution!
This issue occurs when user is not having MASS EMAIL permission. This leads to failing the Post installation script and opposing the package from installation.

Solution steps:

Setup -> Deliverability ->Change access level to All email.
then try to install the package.
Problem solved!